# How does virtual memory get allocated for Mongodb when using MMap

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDb with MMap an in my system I do not have any swap configured. yet when I serverStatus().mem it show that virtual memory is being used. So how is this possible. Am i missig or interperting something wrong?

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      30884904   30602384     282520         60     131676   28925916
-/+ buffers/cache:    1544792   29340112
Swap:            0          0          0


db.serverStatus().mem
{
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 1293,
    "virtual" : 557760,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 276970,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 553940
}
```

Comment: There is no correlation between VM allocation and swap usage. You only get real memory usage (and consequently potential swap usage) once VM allocations are committed.

Comment: @D.SM can we configure/ define how much VM is allocated?

Comment: No, nor should you be trying to do that.